# export to excel vb.net office 2010

Tags: vb.net, export-to-excel

I have a vb.net project, want to export to excel (2010) in English from `axmshflexgrid`. But I have always an exception

> Ancien format ou bibliothèque de type non valide

and an empty excel file with this code.

```
Private Sub cmd_export_excel_Click(ByVal eventSender As System.Object, ByVal eventArgs As System.EventArgs) Handles cmd_export_excel.Click

    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    Dim iRow As Short
    Dim iCol As Short
    Dim objExcl As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    Dim objWk As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
    Dim objSht As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
    Dim iHead As Short
    Dim vHead As Object

    objExcl = New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
    objExcl.Visible = True
    objExcl.UserControl = True


    Dim oldCI As System.Globalization.CultureInfo = _
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = _
        New System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US")

    objWk = objExcl.Workbooks.Add
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCI
    objSht = objWk.Sheets(1)

    vHead = Split(g.FormatString, "|")
    For iHead = 1 To UBound(vHead)
        If Len(Trim(vHead(iHead))) > 0 Then objSht.Cells._Default(1, iHead) = vHead(iHead)
    Next
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.WaitCursor

    For iRow = 0 To g.Rows - 1
        For iCol = 0 To g.get_Cols() - 1
            g.Row = iRow
            g.Col = iCol
            If g.Text <> "" Then


                objSht.Range(NumCol2Lattre(iCol + 1) & "" & iRow + 2 & ":" & NumCol2Lattre(iCol + 1) & "" & iRow + 2 & "").Select()

                objExcl.ActiveCell.Value = CStr(g.Text)

            End If
        Next iCol


    Next iRow

    objExcl.Application.Visible = True


    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Current = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.Default

    objSht = Nothing
    objWk = Nothing
    objExcl = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    objSht = Nothing
    objWk = Nothing
    objExcl = Nothing

    MsgBox("Error In expotation task & " & Err.Description, MsgBoxStyle.Information)
    Err.Clear()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have multiple versions installed?

Whats the version of you interop assemblies?

Compare the version with the created excel instance (objExcl.Version).

It looks like you have a version conflict.

You may have to re-install office2010 in this case(helps most of the time).